# Add Customize Compare Product to Customer Account Page

Tags: customer-account, custom-block

I'm new to magento, and I'm struggling with this problem. I want to add Customize Compare Product to Customer Account Page, so i created my customize block in

```
\template\catalog\product\compare\mycompare.phtml
```

and in my local.xml I add

```
<action method="addLink" translate="label" module="catalog">
     <name>catalog.compare.list</name>
     <path>index.php/catalog/product_compare/index/</path>
     <label>My Compare</label>
</action>

<catalog_product_compare_index>
        <label>Catalog Product Compare List</label>
        <!-- Mage_Catalog -->
        <update handle="customer_account"/>
        <reference name="my.account.wrapper">
        <block type="catalog/product_compare_list" name="catalog.compare.list" template="catalog/product/compare/mycompare.phtml"/>
        </reference>
</catalog_product_compare_index>
```

It's work, but that block was called 2 times. And original compare products (one with new windows when clicked) also changed it's layout! How should I do to fix it??

Comment: so you want to remove the original compare products?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem was because I use same path with pop-up compare product.

```
<path>index.php/catalog/product_compare/index/</path>
```

and this code

```
 <catalog_product_compare_index>
        <label>Catalog Product Compare List</label>
        <!-- Mage_Catalog -->
        <update handle="customer_account"/>
        <reference name="my.account.wrapper">
        <block type="catalog/product_compare_list" name="catalog.compare.list" template="catalog/product/compare/mycompare.phtml"/>
        </reference>
</catalog_product_compare_index>
```

change pop-up compare product layout.

So, what I do here just to create new module. Create `IndexController` with `indexAction`,

```
public function indexAction() {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setTitle($this->__('My Compare'));
        $this->renderLayout(); 
}
```

and change some code in `local.xml`:

```
<action method="addLink" translate="label" module="mycompare">
     <name>mycompare</name>
     <path>mycompare/index</path>
     <label>My Compare</label>
</action>

<mycompare_index>
        <label>Catalog Product Compare List</label>
        <!-- Mage_Catalog -->
        <update handle="customer_account"/>
        <reference name="my.account.wrapper">
        <block type="catalog/product_compare_list" name="mycompare" as="mycompare" template="catalog/product/compare/mycompare.phtml"/>
        </reference>
</mycompare_index>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm not sure what you want to achieve, I will be providing 2 different solutions:

**Solution 1.** If you need to remove the duplication in compare products popup window and add your own custom compare products block template, then you need to implement the following in `local.xml`:

```
<catalog_product_compare_index>
        <update handle="customer_account"/>

        <reference name="content">
            <action method="unsetChild"><name>catalog.compare.list</name></action>
        </reference>            

        <reference name="my.account.wrapper">
            <block type="catalog/product_compare_list" name="catalog.compare.list" template="catalog/product/compare/mycompare.phtml"/>
        </reference>
</catalog_product_compare_index>
```

---

**Solution 2.** If you need to add your custom compare products template block to Customer Account Dashboard page, then you need to implement the following in `local.xml`:

```
<customer_account_index>

    <reference name="my.account.wrapper">
        <block type="catalog/product_compare_list" name="catalog.compare.list" template="catalog/product/compare/mycompare.phtml"/>
    </reference>

</customer_account_index>
```

Comment: @Abbodred1, thx for your answer. I found the culprit. Problem was because I use same path with pop-up compare product. I just need to create new module for my compare path.

Comment: @elune then try to post the solution you end up using as the correct answer.

Comment: @Abbodred1, ok. thx again :)